Have demand charges been analysed from a microeconomic perspective?
Demand charges are commonly used in the electricity sector. My question is, whether anyone has performed a microeconomic analysis of the welfare effects of such pricing assuming a natural monopoly production model?
The basic idea of a demand charge is to charge the consumer according to the maximum consumption. Assume, for the sake of clarity that the consumer demands electricity for the 24 hours of a day. Let the demand be denoted
$$q=(q_1,q_2,...,q_{24})$$
Normally, there would be a price for electricity consumption for every hour and the expenditure would be
$$E = p^\top q = \sum_{t=1}^{24} p_tq_t.$$
However, with a demand charge, the consumer would be charged for the maximal consumption so the expenditure would be
$$E_{max}= \hat p \max\{q\},$$
where $\hat p$ is the price unit price of the maximal consumption.
The purpose is to give the consumer an incentive to lower the maximal level of consumption. The reason why this is important is because most of the costs for electricity transport are costs related to network capacity.
As an example of demand charges see for example this: demand charge example
